# Selecting rows based on priority of a column

Tags: sql

refers below as my source table:

| Entry ID | Name | Colour |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Red |
| 2 | John | *null* |
| 3 | Steve | *null* |
| 4 | Steve | *null* |

I would like to select the entire row based on

- Distinct value of the "name" column
- If "colour" column is not *null*, I will select that row. Otherwise, I will accept the *null* value row.
- Lastly, I will select based on the entry ID which is smaller (the smaller the ID, the earlier the entry ID)

The expected result should be:

| Entry ID | Name | Colour |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Red |
| 3 | Steve | *null* |

I am new to SQL and wondering there's any way to achieve the expected result?

Many thanks and much appreciated.
(pardon my bad English/grammar)

Comment: . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`.  This should work in almost any database:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by colour desc, id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

A descending `order by` puts `NULL` values last, so non-`NULL` rows are chosen first.

An alternative method is:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.colour is not null or
      t.id = (select (case when count(colour) = 0 then min(t2.id) end)
              from t
             )
```